# Populating JTree from database

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtree

I have a table with fields category_id, category_name and parent_category_id. And parent_category_id has values from category_id which represents the parent child relationship. I dont have any fixed level of hierarchy, it may go up to 5 levels or 10 levels and there is no limit to that.. I need a code for how to implement this JTree to make thing work for me. I should be able to implement the same for Menu bar as well.. Please help me with this..

After googling I found this,

```
Map<String, Node> idToNode = new HashMap<String, Node>();   

//create nodes from ResultSet   
while ( resultSet.next() ){       
    Node node = //create node -contains info, parent id, and its own id from ResultSet
    //put node into idToNode, keyed with its id   
}   

//link together   
Iterator<String> it = idToNode.keySet().iterator();   
Node root = null;   
while ( it.hasNext() ){          
    Node node = idToNode.get(it.next());       
    Node parent = idToNode.get(node.getParentId());   
    if ( parent == null ) {  
        root = node;  
    }else{  
       parent.addChild(node);  
    }  
}
```

How do i code those commented instructions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [DefaultMutableTreeNode](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.6/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultMutableTreeNode.html) to create your nodes

Make a map of IDs to nodes - as you get your nodes from the database, store them in the map with the id as their key.

Once you have all your nodes, go through them once more and match their parent ids up, retrieving them from the map.

Assuming your tree is structurally sound in the database, it will be sound here. Pick any node and follow the parent chain the the root.

With the root object, you can create your JTree. :)

Comment: As an aside, I don't have the code necessarily. But I feel there are the tools here that you need to get it done :) Each thing can be looked up as needed.

Comment: i actually dont have time to code this thing up. In another 2 hours i should be able to finish this part so can you find a similar thing for me ? even i am googling for help but nothing helps.. thanks!!

Comment: Each of these activities are clearly documented. I've never used them myself, but the algorithm is sound. I can not imagine a scenario where (assuming you're even a halfway competent developer, which since your post was pretty clear I think is a safe assumption) it would take you more than an hour to do this. It really seems like 10 minutes of code and 20 minutes of debugging the gotchyas, assuming a 2-3 minute compile time.

Comment: "i actually dont have time to code this thing up." -- too precious!