# Which layout should I use to fill a JLayeredPane with JButtons in a order?

Tags: java, swing, layout, jbutton, jlayeredpane

I want to fill the `JLayeredPane` in a order so that when it reaches the right margin it should then start from the next line ans fill the entire box with buttons. I want to design a Point Of Sale screen and its hard for me to arrange the buttons manually.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but what is a "**POS**" screen?  And why a JLayeredPane?  Why not a simple JPanel that uses a Layout manager such as GridLayout?

Comment: Oops!! its Point Of Sale software..

Comment: ok JPanel is fine.. actually i user springlayout but i have problem with button sizes. they are not fixed, the size varies as the text varies.. i want fixed size..

Comment: and gridlayout puts the button just in one row. its not putting in new line as the right border is reached..

Comment: No, a GridLayout should be able to use as many rows as you desire.  For instance, if you know you'll use 9 columns, then you could use a GridLayout(0, 9, 5, 5) for a grid layout that has 9 columns, variable number of rows and 5 pts of vertical and horizontal space between items

Comment: well i am close to it and how do i set the button size ??

Comment: You could try setPreferredSize but this conforms to the size of the container portion that's holding the item.

Comment: i got what i want. thanks for your help!!

Comment: can you help me with this question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5072072/populating-jtree-from-database

Comment: Possibly. But if you find a reply helpful, up-vote it.  A really great reply gets selected as the answer thread.

Comment: but how do i vote for coments ? you have to post me an answer.. i ll definetly vote it up!! and see if you can help me with the other question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the layout manager to auto wrap the components. Maybe the default behavior of the FlowLayout is enough for you.

Otherwise, it is actually fairly easy to develop your own layout manager by subclassing LayoutManager or LayoutManager2. Tip: see how other simple layout managers are implemented to judge the complexity of the task.